# How to log in via facebook using laravel socialite?

Tags: mysql, laravel, facebook, eloquent, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to authenticate a user via Facebook using laravel socialite. When I click my login with the Facebook button, it does not redirect to facebook pop up rather it logged in as a user and redirect back to my index page.

Here is my controller

```
 public function redirectToFacebook() {
     return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
 }

 public function handleFacebookCallback() {
      $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
      $this->registerOrLoginUser($user);

     // Return home after login
     return redirect()->route('frontend.index');
 }

  protected function registerOrLoginUser($data) {
      $user = Customer::where('email', '=', $data->email)->first();
          if (!$user) {
                $user              = new Customer();
                $user->name        = $data->name;
                $user->email       = $data->email;
                $user->save();
     }

            Auth::guard('customer')->login($user);
        }
```

When clicking on the login button it does not redirect to Facebook, it creates a new customer or logged a customer. What is wrong with my code? and what is the solution?

Comment: You might be logged in on facebook in your browser. Check facebook.com once in your browser.

Comment: is it possible to show facebook pop up when click on login with facebook everytime?

Comment: Yes and that is what happens pop up appears everytime. But if you are logged in on your facebook account in browser it directly redirects into your website as logged in user